# Is the tense within this sentence consistent? Confusion between 'ed' and 'ing'

Tags: tenses

I have a few sentences in my resume that have been prompted by an auto-resume reviewer that my tenses may not be correct.
Reading the sentence back to myself, it does feel a bit off now that they said so but I'm not sure if it is.
My confusion and what I think it has caught on, is the verbs ending in 'ed' and then 'ing', am I talking in the same tense by keeping them in 1 sentence or am I unintentionally switching between tenses?

> -Designed and deployed coding scripts, manipulating and interacting with 100s of computers, thus streamlining the workflow of the company

> -Implemented APIs in an application, facilitating the allocation of employees’ job projects

> -Facilitated the transition of a colleageue's new role by conducting training sessions and providing support

Comment: Your tenses are just right. AI cannot distinguish between clauses or who the agent was in your bullets. You could shut autocorrect up by changing the API bullet to "which facilitated."

Comment: I'd shift focus on #3: Trained new colleague and provided ongoing support to make the transition both easier and more productive.

Comment: Ok thats reassuring to know thanks, I will make those changes

Comment: I would probably reword #1 to say "designed... scripts that manipulate and interact with hundreds of computers" if that's what you mean.  "designed... scripts, manipulating" does feel weird to me.

Comment: You do realise, don't you, that none of your examples is a sentence, but just a series of VPs?

Comment: @BillJ That's common in resume bullet points. The subject "I" is implicit.

Comment: @BillJ It's a list of accomplishments.

Comment: Could you first look back at '… reviewer that my tenses may not be correct' and try to rephrase that in correct English? (Never mind what comes after…)

Comment: How does this not belong to SE Writing, or English Language Learning, rather than here in ELU?

Only a guess could explain 'My confusion and what I think it has caught on…'.

If the problem is whether verbs end in 'ed' and or 'ing' then please, go to ELL.

Whence comes any suggestion you switched tenses?

Isn't the real problem, what's meant by 'Is the tense within this sentence consistent' is not at all supported by the exposition?